# Fragment with two listviews where first adapter overrides the second adapter

Tags: android-fragments, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

The issue is that the display constructed by the first adapter is replaced by the display constructed by the second adapter when it gets it is data loaded via mAdapter2.changeCursor(cursor).

My Fragment has two ListViews in a single layout that gets inflated in the onCreateView method.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout with two list views
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shipment_details, null);

    // Define list view for shipment details
    ListView lis1 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list1);
    mAdapter1 = new CursorAdapter1(getActivity(), null, 1);
    list1.setAdapter(mAdapter1);

    // Define list view for event list
    ListView list2 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list2);
    mAdapter2 = new CursorAdapter2(getActivity(), null, 1);
    eventView.setAdapter(mAdapter1);
    return view;
```

Then loading data with two cursors, which is working fine, until the second adapter is called in onLoadFinished(Loader cursorLoader, Cursor cursor).

Both adapters have a newVies and bindView.

First adapter:

```
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_layout1, parent);
}
```

Second adapter:

```
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_layout2, parent);
}
```

How to resolve that the adapters do not override?

Comment: In your code you are inflating list2 from R.id.list2 but setting the adapter to eventView object. I can't see where eventView was initialized. Are you sure list1 and eventView aren't referencing to the same object in the memory?

Comment: Also if this code snippet is straight out of your project, try to give relevant names to variables. list1, list2, adapter1, adapter2 can get really confusing at times.